# 2.93 - how to add Edge selection to right click menu?

Tags: selection-tools

2.93 - was practicing face and edge selection and not getting any of the "alt" functions to work. how to add Edge selection to right click menu? something like, Left Mouse select edge, right click SELECT RING or LOOP

Comment: How would Blender know which loop you want selected? - The right-click menu pops up wherever you click, even off your object. I'd have thought it would be much better to find out why your ALT key isn't working and sort that out!

Comment: Blender Alt click selects each edge at a time, or shortest path but not a loop of edges. (at least not figured out yet)  
Silo double click an edge and it selects the loop or Right Click Menu  https://i.postimg.cc/V6KWy7qJ/Silo-Select.jpg

Comment: There are quite a few answers as to why loop selection fails on Stack Exchange. It's often because one of the edges isn't on an ngon so the loop doesn't know which direction to go. You could also try ALT SHIFT click which lots of people seem to use by default although using SHIFT shouldn't really be necessary unless selecting more than one loop.